# Shiny R randomForest Error

Tags: r, machine-learning, shiny, kaggle

I am trying to use Shiny app and found out that below code works.

**ui.R:**

```
data(Titanic)
head(as.data.frame(Titanic),5)
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Titanic Survival Calculator"),
  sidebarPanel(
    p("Select person attributes to calculate his/her chances of surviving of 
the titanic sinking."),
    selectInput("c", label =h3("Crew/Passenger:"), list("1st Class Passenger" = "1st","2nd Class Passenger" = "2nd", "3rd Class Passenger" = "3rd", "Crew Member" = "Crew")),
radioButtons("s", label = h3("Sex:"),
             choices = list("Male" = "Male", "Female" = "Female"), 
             selected = "Female"),
radioButtons("a", label = h3("Age:"),
             choices = list("Child" = "Child", "Adult" = "Adult"),
             selected = "Adult")),
  mainPanel(
h3("Survival Probability:"),
h4(textOutput('prob')),
p("Please note that this is estimated probability based on a logistic regression model."),
p("That means this value is slightly different than historical survival rate."))))
```

**server.R:**

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
data(Titanic)
tit <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
tit_glm <- glm(Survived ~ Class + Sex + Age, binomial, tit, tit$Freq)

pred_tit <- function(class, sex, age ){
  inputdata <- c(class, sex, age)
  pred_data <- as.data.frame(t(inputdata))
  colnames(pred_data) <- c("Class", "Sex", "Age")
  surv_prob <- predict(tit_glm,pred_data , type = "response" )
  return(surv_prob)
}

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
output$prob <- renderText({pred_tit(input$c,input$s, input$a)})
  })
```

However, I want to use Randomforest model instead of GLM.  I tried to use randomforest by typing simple code

```
tit_glm <- randomForest(Survived ~ ., tit)
```

But I am keep getting error message.  can somebody help me please?

Comment: It works fine for me. Have you sourced the library`randomForest`? Your code doesn't show that you've sourced it.

Comment: Thaks for reply. Yes i sourced it but getting error. Can i please see your whole code? Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
tit_glm <- randomForest(Survived ~ ., tit)
```

will give error, because this means that you are using all the rest of the features for model training. However, this is not possible, as there are many features which are mostly NA's and there are a few of them which have near zero variance.

First try to remove the features, that are mostly NA's, and then remove the near zero variance features.